# Is it possible to construct primes with arbitrary messages in them?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, computer-science

**Motivation:**
A friend of mine told me that the number gained by interpreting the binary code of is quite often a prime. A slight copyright themed discussion later and after developing an algorithm to make any visual medium a prime:

`While(notPrime):
    mutate`

The question arose if there is a wasteful lossless encoding of the form:

Number Data Encodinginformation

e.g.:

Encode "a" as

10110000101111

which is:

`1 (number sought to make it prime)
01100001(ascii for "a")
0111(encoding of length of String)
1(always last number to ensure the number is odd)`

**Math Question:**

given a number $n$ coprime to $b$ is there a prime of the form
$$p=n+\sum_{i=k}^m a_ib^i$$
where $a_i\in\{0,\ldots,b-1\}$, $m$ is arbitrary and $k=\lceil log_b(n) \rceil$?

Comment: Presumably, $b=2$ is not allowed ?

Comment: I was thinking about asking the question with **only** $b=2$.

Comment: If $a_i\in \{0,\ldots,b-1\}$, then it's true by Dirichlet's theorem. In fact, there will be infinitely many such primes.

Comment: EDIT: changed the question to incorporate $a_i\in \{0,\ldots,b-1\}$

Comment: Seems possible, can you elaborate? I thought you would need the form $n+j*b$ for the Dirichlet series? Is there a corollary i am forgetting?

Comment: Do you realize that $\sum_{i=k}^m a_ib^i$ can be any number, times $b^k$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Yves and Mastrem pointed out: One can find infinitly many of those primes because of [Dirichlets Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions)
one just has to realize that

$n+\sum_{i=k}^ma_ib^i = n + b^k \sum_{i=0}^m\tilde{a}_ib^i$

and that trivially $a$ is coprime to $b^k$ as it is coprime to $b$.